# Vertical align text inside a bootstrap layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried many of the different methods on google/stackoverflow etc in order to vertically align the text within my code but I am having a lot of difficulty getting there.

My code is a form where the user can write in 'doom name' and text appears on the picture.

I am simply trying to vertically align the text that gets entered onto the picture so that it looks as it would appear in real life once printed.

I have tried all the methods but this is my first website and this troubleshooting is above me.

Here's a bootply for ya'll.
http://www.bootply.com/NQWhZArz7D

Thanks a lot

(don't worry about any responsive issues it's all sorted on my code)

Edit: must be compatible with being able to enter multiple lines of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this by using the `line-height` same as that of the height

Try:-

```
   .centering{
     line-height:324px;
   }
```

**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/MWOfKnQpAC)**

This will work fine if it is a single line of text, if the text is long enough that it wraps down then line height will be applied to each of those lines, So chose this method based on your requirement.

Another way is to use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` which will then respect vertical alignment.

Ex:-

```
<div class="col-xs-12 table">
    <p class="centering text-center">Toaster Apocalypse</p>
</div>
```

and

```
.table {
  display:table;
}

.centering{ /* or use a meaningfule rule like .table .table-cell*/
   display:table-cell;
   width:100%;
}
```

and give its parent container `display:table`

**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Nl4TTV0UTK)**

Take a look at some of the [centering techniques here](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)